# Can a MySQL event delete multiple rows instantly?

Tags: mysql, sql

Well i am doing my diploma thesis and i had an idea in mind for the database of the program i am designing. I am doing a Gym Membership Manager and i the main purpose is to keep records of the clients memberships, my tables are as follows:

|**Client Info**|

*-ID*

*+Name*

|**Client Membership**|

*Client ID*

*Membership ID*

*-Starting Date*

*-Ending Date*

|**Expired Memberships**|

*+Client Name*

*+Ending Date*

The event i have defined is as follows:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `expired_memberships`
SET
    `Client Name` =(
    SELECT
        CI.`Name`
    FROM
        `client_info` AS CI
    INNER JOIN `client_membership` AS CM
    ON
        CI.`client_id` = CM.`Client ID`
    WHERE
        CM.`Ending Date` < CURRENT_DATE()
    ),
        `Ending Date` = CURRENT_DATE();

    DELETE
FROM
    `client_membership`
WHERE
    `Ending Date` < CURRENT_DATE();
    END
```

I searched around the internet on how to check if a event works because i was doubting that it would work and i found a thread here in stackoverflow saying to copy paste the event in a stored procedure and run it but when i tried it said subquery has more than one result because there were two rows to delete on the **client_membership** table, i thought if i should have added like for each row but i'm not sure. The main idea of the event is to transfer records from client_memberships to expired_memberships. HELP PLS!

Comment: There's no problem with deleting multiple rows. Are you sure the error is on the `DELETE`, not the `INSERT`? The assignment `SET Client Name = (SELECT...)` won't work if the subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: shorten the time that it fires, lets say in one minute and enable the general logl, so you can see what happesn in one minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your insert to a form that you can save as amny as you need

```
INSERT INTO `expired_memberships`
SELECT
    CI.`Name`,CURRENT_DATE()
FROM
    `client_info` AS CI
INNER JOIN `client_membership` AS CM
ON
    CI.`client_id` = CM.`Client ID`
WHERE
    CM.`Ending Date` < CURRENT_DATE();
```

And of course you can delete multiple rows, if need be.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but it still displays the error that the subquery returns more than one row when there are two memberships that are expired. I tried this on the stored procedure but i don't know if it would work on the event. I will try the event to be run and see if it works.

Comment: please show me the complete error message, that is to vage to respond. It will only run in and event when  it runsn in the sored procwecure as well, ou can coll that procedure from then event.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly! I didn't realize the changes sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `INSERT`. There's more than one membership that expired, but you can only assign one value to `Client Name`.

You should use the `SELECT` as the source of the `INSERT` data rather than assigning a subquery to a single column.

```
INSERT INTO expired_membersips (`Client Name`, `Ending Date`)
SELECT CI.Name, CURRENT_DATE()
FROM client_info AS CI
INNER JOIN `client_membership` AS CM
ON CI.`client_id` = CM.`Client ID`
WHERE CM.`Ending Date` < CURRENT_DATE()
```